# Rally webservices api v 1.36 <OperationResultError>Could not update: Could not write changes in Unit Of Work</OperationResultError>

Tags: ruby, web-services, rest, rally

I am using rally webservices api v 1.36 and I am getting this error when I try to create a new rally item.Could not update: Could not write changes in Unit Of Work. Code was working fine a week back but now it is not working. I am using ruby gem rally_rest_api. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use an equivalent curl command or hit the endpoint using a browser REST client to see if you get the same error. Use the current v2.0 of WS API. If you get the same error, post your create URL here, otherwise there is no enough information to know what is happening. Try curl or browser REST client with the payload equivalent to the attribute settings you do in your Ruby code.

To narrow it down you may also reduce the number of attribute you set and see when it starts working, if ever. For example if you create a user story and the only required field is Name, try to create a story while only setting the Name and see if that succeeds, and keep adding attributes until you replicate the error.

rally_rest_api is no longer supported, it is old. The same goes for 1.36 of WS API. See deprecation schedule [here](https://help.rallydev.com/web-services-api-deprecation-policy). There is new [Ruby REST toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby) that uses rally_api gem.

Comment: Thanks Nickm. I was also planning to do the same thing. Thanks for your help. This happens only with my test env and not in prod env.